# How can I call an ant task in a shell script?

Tags: android, bash, shell, deployment, ant

I would like to call:

```
ant release
```

then I would like to call a script I have

```
sh deploy-app.sh
```

How can I do this in a script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a wrapper script:

```
ant release
deploy-app.sh
```

(Assuming `deploy-app.sh` is `chmod u+x`.)

Comment: @SheehanAlam It's easier than the alternative, calling a script from Ant; don't know which is better in your case. See [here for details](http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#batch-shell-execute).